# Invalid field 'contact_id.is_deceased' Apiv4

Tags: wordpress, api, apiv4

CiviCRM 5.61.2., wordpress.

- Hovering over icons on search results page brings "where was an error processing your request.." message and **Invalid field 'contact_id.is_deceased'** message
- Happens only for "subscribers" wordpress role, even if "CiviCRM: access AJAX API" and "CiviCRM: view all contacts" allowed for everyone ( including anonymous)
- Looks similar to https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2507 at first sight but is not the same
- contact_id.is_deceased is being called in:

  - /civicrm/api/v3/Email.php
  - /civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Task/EmailTrait.php
  - /civicrm/CRM/Profile/Page/Dynamic.php
    Additionally, in/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/persist/contribute/dyn/crm-l10n.48bc1baa4052e4cf59989414d9b48136.js - but only on my local copy, remote one ( where the issue happens ) does not have this file.

Backtrace:

```
   #line: 711
   trace: {
     wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Query/Api4SelectQuery.php:711 {
       Civi\Api4\Query\Api4SelectQuery->getField($expr, $strict = false)
       › if ($strict && $field === NULL) {
       ›   throw new \CRM_Core_Exception("Invalid field '$fieldName'");
       › }
     }
     wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Query/Api4SelectQuery.php:656 { …}
     wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Query/Api4SelectQuery.php:494 { …}
     wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Query/Api4SelectQuery.php:464 { …}
     wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Query/Api4SelectQuery.php:304 { …}
     wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Query/Api4SelectQuery.php:156 { …}
     wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Query/Api4SelectQuery.php:171 { …}
     wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Generic/DAOGetAction.php:124 { …}
     wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Generic/DAOGetAction.php:111 { …}
     wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Provider/ActionObjectProvider.php:72 { …}
     wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php:158 { …}
     wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Generic/AbstractAction.php:250 { …}
     wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Profile/Page/Dynamic.php:450 { …}
     wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Profile/Page/Dynamic.php:332 { …}
     wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Profile/Page/View.php:91 { …}
     wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Profile/Page/View.php:159 { …}
```

**What would it be?**
[image]

Comment: Can you reproduce it on dmaster?  If so, please open an issue at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/

Comment: Wish I could: none of WP demos available here https://civicrm.org/demo?field_language_value=1&field_cms_demo_value=wordpress allow me to reproduce the exact setup.

Comment: Spoke too soon. I've edited my answer because I can't reproduce. See https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4458

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That backtrace seems to point to [this change](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/commit/b7edabe813db467aff6dd1ea083d798089198655) as the culprit, however after several attempts I've been unable to reproduce that error. We can continue discussion on this issue: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/4458